# how to serve a static sub site as part of svelte app

Tags: routes, static, svelte, sveltekit, docusaurus

I'm trying to integrate docusaurus to my svelteKit app, as a documentation for my devs. I would like to build my doc to static files and then serve them under the `/doc` endpoint of my app.

**Problem** : I don't know the proper way to do this with a name based router

My architecture looks like this :

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ static/
│  ├─ favicon.ico
│  ├─ robots.txt
├─ src/
│  ├─ docs/
│  │  ├─ build/   <--- static files are here
│  ├─ routes/
```

I could achieve this with an express server, but this seem a bit overkill as the doc will be available only in devMode.

I also tried to put the static files in the static directory but docusaurus doesn't like this and this folders purpose seems to be to serve files, and not entire "sub-apps".

I've also tried to create an alias to the 'build/index.html' file and include it in a `+page.svelte` route but then, the routing is not functionnal in my doc.

Is what I'm doing a bad idea ? How do you guys handle your dev docs for your projects ?

Comment: For simple docs I would just use plain Markdown files, no need to serve anything.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get something like this semi working by putting my docs in `static/docs` Navigating to `/docs/index.html` works while the prettier `/docs/`does not.

To then get the pretty links working I added this plugin to `vite.config.ts`

```
import { purgeCss } from 'vite-plugin-tailwind-purgecss';
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        purgeCss(),
        {
            name: 'docs-index',
            configureServer(server) {
                server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
                    if (req.url?.startsWith('/docs')) {
                        req.url = req.url + '/index.html';
                    }
                    next();
                });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Now navigating to `/docs/` works, `/docs` does not for me, though some content was rendered so could be something odd about `mkdocs` rendered documentation specifically rather than SvelteKit / Vite.